# How to make selected text on EditText underlined?

Tags: java, android, html

I have an EditText. I need to underline a text when the user presses a button after selecting.
I have tried using this code:

```
myEditText.setText(HtmlCompat.FromHtml("<u>" + selection + "</u>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

This works, however, if I have previously set bold (or italics, for example), when the above code gets called, the Bold/Italics not only get back to normal, but the entire formatting gets messed up too.
Is there any way that I could just toggle the underlining in the selected text without messing everything up?

Comment: How do you get the selection?

Comment: @Mehmed  I use: int start = myEditText.getSelectionStart(); int end = myEditText.getSelectionEnd(); String selection = myEditText.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using [`Spannable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable) to format parts of your `EditText` text, and to specifically underline a part of it, you can use [`UnderlineSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan)

[`spannable.setSpan()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int)) will let you format a certain portion of your `EditText` text with a start and end indices.

```
EditText editText = findViewById(...);
Button btn = findViewById(...);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(editText.getText().toString());
        spannable.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 
                            editText.getSelectionStart(), // start index
                            editText.getSelectionEnd(), // end index
                            0);
        editText.setText(spannable);
    }
});
```